# I accidentally formatted the wrong volume - is it possible to restore the previous Ext4 filesystem?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, ext4

I know that a similar question has already been asked. This morning I accidentally formatted the wrong volume, containing mostly video files (about 30GB each).

I am currently trying to restore the files with Photorec, however it does not seem to work very well - all restored files are corrupted.

The volume is a Cryptsetup Luks ext4 volume (however not reformatted with LuksFormat, just mkfs.ext4)

Is it somehow possible to recover the old superblocks/journals? (And if yes, would that actually help restoring the old filesystem?)

Comment: [Sorry, no][1].  If Photorec can't help you your SOL


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/43779/is-it-possible-to-unformat-an-ext4-partition-that-previously-had-an-ext4-partiti

Comment: That link is talking about an encrypted filesystem though, which had the header deleted.

Comment: You should try with testdisk. I had decent results recovering an ext4 partition

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is not possible to recover the old ext4 filesystem. I am currently recovering some files with Photorec, with mixed success.

A response from the developing of UFS Explorer is as follow:

> The reason is ext4 on time of format destroys completely *all* inodes
>   and even file system journal so volume only contains file data;
>   usually it is fragmented. Ext4 uses special tree structure to store
>   map of file fragments and this tree is stored in inodes that are wiped
>   with zeros.
>
> It’s recommended to continue using PhotoRec and other similar free
>   utilities in attempt to get some data back; no commercial software
>   will help you more in this case.

As they are experts on that field and their statement is backed up by Wikipedia, I would therefore answer the question myself with the conclusion that it is not possible to restore the whole filesystem.